# is there a way to display product gallery images via cdn

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, cdn

I have three issues that require a solution please. Is there a way to show product gallery images externally using a cdn but instead of pointing to that exact image url only point to the folder that has that product images which then results in showing all the images in that folder as the product gallery images.

The main reason why I would like to do this is I have 5000 products and over 20,000 variations. Now our supplier has provided us a csv and imagery seperate but linking these will take quite a while.

Rather what I would like to achieve is to upload csv without imagery to site using wp all import and then once completed, upload a csv containing all the imagery folders  and link it via say sku (folder names are named as overall product sku) so the right images appear for the right products

Now fifu WordPress plugin only allows direct cdn urls and folders is not possible so what is the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: How does FIFU work? Does it create an entry in your media gallery that's just served from an external URL, or does it override the featured image handling so that there's no media gallery entry at all?

Comment: Because I think your options here are the same as that: either you come up with a way to add externally-hosted images into the media gallery and attach them to your products, which then WooCommerce and your theme would handle correctly as if they were locally-hosted images, or you hook into the WooCommerce product gallery code to use your per-SKU directory instead. (Which I guess you would have to have an entry in the local database for, e.g. in the postmeta, with cached metadata about the remote images anyway.)

Comment: It might be worth asking the FIFU people about this anyway, since this is a similar problem to the one they've already solved, to see if it's something they can support for you easily. But I'd guess you'll have to write some code for this yourself.